# How to calculate this limit for a biological model?

Tags: limits, biology

This is from a mathematical biology exam:

[image]

I’ve answered parts $a)$ to $f)$ absolutely fine but I’m struggling with what I presume is the final mark of part $f)$.

I’ve solved the equation directly to obtain:

$$N(t)=\frac{(1-k)N_0 e^{(1-k)t}}{1-k-N_0 +N_0e^{(1-k)t}}$$

Now I know I need to examine the cases when $1-k<0$ and $1-k>0$. I know that when $1-k<0$ clearly $N(t)\rightarrow 0$ but I don’t understand the behaviour when $1-k>0$. I know that $N(t)\rightarrow 1-k$ when $1-k>0$ as it needs to agree with the steady state but I just don’t understand how to show this. Could someone explain this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing numerator and denominator of the right hand side of the equation
$$N(t)=\frac{(1-k)N_0 e^{(1-k)t}}{1-k-N_0 +N_0e^{(1-k)t}}$$
by $N_0e^{(1-k)t}$ you get
$$N(t)=\frac{(1-k)}{((1-k)/N_0-1)e^{-(1-k)t} +1}$$

As $1-k$ is supposed to be strictly positive, you have
$$\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} ((1-k)/N_0-1)e^{-(1-k)t} = 0$$

Hence the desired result $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} N(t) = 1-k$

Comment: Thank you so much!